# Solr not backing up core

Tags: solr

I'm trying to backup a Solr core (Solr 8.1.1 in standalone mode). I added the replication requestHandler as per https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/index-replication.html#configuring-the-replicationhandler

When I run /solr/core/replication?command=backup it returns:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "status":"OK"}
```

But when running /solr/core/replication?command=details it returns:

```
...
"backup":[
      "exception","/opt/solr-8.1.1/server/solr/core/data/restore.20200414231901420/_22sklw_Lucene50_0.tim"]}}
```

When I specify the backup name and location (e.g. /solr-backups/, which is owned by the solr user) it never creates any files.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get solr to create a backup?

Edit:
This is showing in the log files:

```
2021-04-23 01:21:18.056 ERROR (Thread-136) [   ] o.a.s.h.SnapShooter Exception while creating snapshot
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/solr-8.1.1/server/solr/core/data/restore.20200414231901420/_22ufue_1mh0.liv
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
        at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:238) ~[lucene-core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:15:24]
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.openInput(NRTCachingDirectory.java:181) ~[lucene-core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:15:24]
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Directory.copyFrom(Directory.java:181) ~[lucene-core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:15:24]
        at org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.LocalFileSystemRepository.copyFileFrom(LocalFileSystemRepository.java:145) ~[solr-core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:01]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapShooter.createSnapshot(SnapShooter.java:238) ~[solr-core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:01]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapShooter.lambda$createSnapAsync$2(SnapShooter.java:205) ~[solr-core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:01]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
```

Comment: Does the Solr log show anything useful?

Comment: Have added the log messages to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a regression of a bug from earlier Solr that was re-introduced in 8.0.0. It was fixed in 8.4.0 apparently

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13872